# Efficiently plot large data figures

Tags: matlab, pdf-generation

I have large vectors (O(10^6) elements) that I need to plot. Here is the script that I use for my figure:

```
close all
fig1 = figure(1);
set(fig1,'Visible','off');
scatter(T_scatter,H2_scatter,5.0,'MarkerEdgeColor','black','MarkerFaceColor','black')
hold on
plot(T_lam,H2_lam,'LineWidth',2.3,'Color','red')
axis([200 1800 0 0.012])
xlabel('T','FontSize',20)
ylabel('H2','FontSize',20)
saveas(fig1,'plots/hydrogen/scatter_H2.pdf')
```

Not displaying the picture with `'Visible','off'` helped a bit but this operation takes quite some time. Beside being very time consuming, the PDFs are huge (tens to hundreds of MB) which then make then realistically unusable for making a report (I used LateX). So I end up making a picture copy of the PDF and save it in the `png` format, which also take a long time. Note that if I save the figure into a `png` directly from my MATLAB, it either takes a very very long time to generate or just crashes the GUI.

When saving the PDF, instead of taking a picture of the plot like I want, I feel like the PDF saves the location of every single data point, which is the cause of all my trouble. Is there a way to save the PDF just as a picture? I do not really know much of picture formats so feel free to let me know if I am not tackling the problem correctly.

Comment: If you are using LaTeX you really should be saving your plots in the `eps` format. You can compress `pdf` and `eps` files to remove some of the extra information within them but yet still retain the visual aspect.

Comment: I wonder if it would be much smaller in size if you save it as a scalable vector svg instead...